# Is there any noise reduction method in MediaCapture?

Tags: audio, uwp

I am using [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture#capture-audio) to capture audio in my case from a mic and save it as mp3. It works, but the sound quality seems to be very poor when compared to an audio file recorded at the same time (same input) by any other programs like the wavepad. So my question is, is there any noise reduction technique or some other way to improve the audio quality captured through MediaCapture? Please note, I am already using AudioEncodingQuality.High in the CreateMp3 method, as shown in the following code.

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("audio.mp3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
_mediaRecording = await mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync(
        MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.High), file);
await _mediaRecording.StartAsync();
```

[Here are the recorded files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/96qso6645uojcqa/AABhlxDsdQMbUDqxnGrnMMA1a?dl=0) by both apps.

Comment: You could try to get buffers from `AudioFrame` to process the data frame and implement noise reduction. Refer to the [Audio Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs) and [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/audiocreation/).

Comment: Okay, Let me look into it to see whether it gives me a noise-free recording.

Comment: Please feel free to contact us if you have any concern.